# How to limit update_layout margins only to one subplot in Plotly / Dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

In a 2 row, 1 column layout, the `main` plot is positioned above `sub`.

```
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=main_data, name='main',
                             line=dict(color='white', width=1), row=1, col=1)

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index, y=sub_data, name='sub', row=2, col=1)
```

When I use `update_layout` as follows:

```
    fig.update_layout(height=400, margin=dict(t=30, b=15, l=15), pad=20)
```

the padding is applied to **both** `main` and `sub`.

Is there a way to have padding apply only to `main`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fig.update_layout()`](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#updating-figure-layouts) applies only to the attributes of the *entire* figure, and that's why you can't address attributes of subplots with `fig.update_layout(row = 2, col = 2)` like you can with `fig.update_traces(row, col)`. So depending on what you'd like to achieve here, you're going to have to adjust the appearance of your subplots through [`specs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvCe8.png) and / or `row_heights` and [`column_widths`](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#customize-subplot-column-widths-and-row-heights) in your [`make_subplots()`](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#multiple-subplots) call.

Here's an example using both approaches:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=5, cols=2,
    column_widths = [0.7, 0.3],
    row_heights = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1],
    specs=[[{}, {"rowspan": 2}],
           [{}, None],
           [{"rowspan": 2, "colspan": 2}, None],
           [None, None],
           [{}, {}]],
#     print_grid=True
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2], name="(1,1)"), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2], name="(1,2)"), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2], name="(2,1)"), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2], name="(3,1)"), row=3, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2], name="(5,1)"), row=5, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2], name="(5,2)"), row=5, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="specs examples")
fig.show()
```